# Maclaurin expansion series at $x=0$

Tags: power-series

I have the function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \dfrac{e^{x}-1}{x}, & x\neq0 \\ 1, & x=0 \end{array}\right.$$
And I gotta find its Maclaurin expansion series.

I know how to find the one from $\dfrac{e^{x}-1}{x}$. But how do get a function that $f(0)=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^x - 1 = \sum_{k\ge 1} {x^k\over k!}.$$
Now divide by $x$ and you are done.

Comment: This function has a removable singularity at 0.

Comment: So the answer is $$\sum\frac{x^{k}}{(k+1)!}$$ for $k\geq0$?

Comment: Just re-index the sum!

Answer (score 1):

Your constant is equal to 1, as your function approaches 1 when x=0. So set your constant to 1 and just use derivatives to approximate $\dfrac{e^{x}-1}{x}$  around x=0.